# Scala FunctionN tupled vs curried result interpretation

Tags: scala

I am just wrapping my head a little around Scala functionN `curried` and `tupled`

1. First interpreting some result from my Scala worksheet that i am not sure off

```
def pairfunc(e1:Int, e2:Int): Int = e1 + e2 //pairfunc: (e1: Int, e2: Int)Int (OK a Method)

(pairfunc(_,_)).curried. // Int => (Int => Int) = scala.Function2<function>

val ef1: Int => Int = e1 => e1 * 2 //Int => Int = <function> (OK Function1)

val ef2: (Int, Int) => Int = (e1, e2) => e1 + e2 //(Int, Int) => Int = <function> (OK Function1 with Tuple)

val ef22: Int => Int => Int = e1 => e2 => e1 + e2 //Int => (Int => Int) (OK curried Function)
```

What I don't get is why

```
(pairfunc(_,_)).curried
```

gives

```
Int => (Int => Int) = scala.Function2<function>
```

and

```
val ef22: Int => Int => Int = e1 => e2 => e1 + e2
```

gives

```
Int => (Int => Int) = <function>
```

They are supposed to be the same thing, so why one is `scala.Function2<function>` and the other simply `<function>`

2. Generally speaking, although it kind of make sense in my head, I have yet to properly articulate the reason for the **tupling** business. If someone could articulate that cleanly that would help to wrap up.

Comment: `scala.Function2<function>` that seems like an implementation detail, the actual type is a **Function1** `Int => (Int, Int)`. Probably `curried` is implemented in **Fuction2** as an inner class, but again you shouldn't need to worry about that - _" I have yet to properly articulate the reason for the tupling business"_ I did not understand that part, care to elaborate?

Comment: Why do we have the tuple function in the first place ?

Comment: WDYM with tuple function? You mean why do we have **Function2**, **Function3**, ... and so on, when we could just use curried **Function1** like in Haskell?

Comment: Sounds like you are already starting to articulate the answer. You should not assume that I know haskell tho ?

Comment: Just trying to make sure I understand the question. If that was indeed the question _(why having **Function2**, etc)_ then the answer is the same as why we have **Tuple3**, etc. Convenience, especially on a strict language like **Scala** it is easier to have things like a function of two arguments or a tuple of three values rather than saying a function that returns a function that returns a value, as well as a tuple whose second element is also a tuple. - but yeah, they are all _"unnecessary"_ but I personally am very grateful they exist, they make learning and using the language easier.

Comment: Looks like the `toString` method is simply not overridden the same way. I got the output as `scala.Function2$$Lambda$8576/819881548@48c9e826` in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ysthakur/CieSl3tkQDuScfhI8vApNw/55), suggesting that the curried function came from an anonymous class inside the `curried` function in `Function2`.

Comment: You should respond with Answer to the question, you have great answers right there. I understand what you. Also thank god i started to read a bit of haskel it makes understanding all that scala does a bit easier, including your answer. On  another note, i think that is what make the language a bit hard to learn for some, because a massive amount of the theoretical background is elsewhere. What i mean, is even if haskell has some advance thing, it is easier to understand, because everything is part of the same conceptualization of things. While in scala, some things may  sound alien sometime

Comment: I mean official Answer, so i can upvote it :) !!!

Comment: @MaatDeamon Come on, don't hate on Java. Considering how old it is and the backward compatibility problems they have, I think it's admirable how far it's come.

Comment: @user Fair Point. This was just a kind academic comment, rather than a practical Business view of things, which Java does very well with backward compatibility. The appraoch however has its limit in my humble opinion

Comment: @MaatDeamon the problem is that such answer is rather subjective and is just my personal believe not the real reason why the creators did it _(since only the creators themselves could answer that)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because of the [`unspecialized`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/unspecialized.html) annotation on `Function2`'s [`curried`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/Function2.scala#L43) method.

The other methods that you made likely had `toString` overridden to say `<function1>` and `<function2>`, but since the `curried` method is annotated with `unspecialized`, it doesn't generate a new method that produces a `Function1` instance with a pretty `toString`. They likely did this to reduce code bloat, because `Function2`'s [type parameters](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/Function2.scala#L34) are all annotated with `@specialized`.

I don't know why you got the output `scala.Function2<function>` in your worksheet, but in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ysthakur/CieSl3tkQDuScfhI8vApNw/55), I got `scala.Function2$$Lambda$8576/819881548@48c9e826`, which tells us that it came from a lambda used inside `Function2`.